# c++ struct function that returns a new struct that dynamically allocated and accepts a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

i am trying to write a function that returns a new dynamically allocated
struct pointer and i am having trouble with the returning of the pointer. 
i have gotten this to work if i am just returning a struct. but i can not figure out how to pass fract back. any help would be great.

```
struct fraction
{
    int n;
    int d;
    int gcd = 0;
};

class Worker
{
private:
    fraction * fract = new fraction;

public:

    Worker();
    // prototypes
    fraction* gcd(fraction *);
};

fraction Worker:: *gcd(fraction *f)
{


    int n= f->n;
    int d = f->d;
    int r = 0;
    do
    {
        r = n % d;
        n = d;
        d = r;
    } while (d > 0);
    fract->d = f->d;
    fract->n = f->n;
    fract->gcd = n;

    return fract;

}
```

Comment: Why is `fract` a class member? Do you want to return a new `fract` with each call to `gcd`, or the same one?

Comment: your code does not compile, you need `fraction* Worker::gcd(fraction *f)` instead of `fraction Worker:: *gcd(fraction *f)`. Also, who's going to release the memory for the `fraction*` member? You need a destructor in which to delete the memory.

Comment: Thank you. and i have a deconstruct later in the program that deals with fraction and fract. i plan to use the pointers for other functions

Comment: `fraction * fract = new fraction;` - this is horrible, change to `fraction fract;`  (and change `->` to `.` in your function)

Comment: can you explain why you didn't want `gcd` to return `fract`? it's hard to answer the question without knowing what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    Fraction() {}
    Fraction( int numerator, int denominator ) :
        num( numerator ),
        den( denominator )
    {}
}; // Fraction

class FractionWithGCD {
private:
    Fraction m_fraction;
    int      m_gcd;

public:
    FractionWithGCD(); // Default
    FractionWithGCD( int numerator, int denominator );
    FractionWithGCD( Fraction& fraction );

    int getGCD() const { return m_gcd; }
    Fraction getFraction() const { return m_fraction; }

    void calculateGCD( int numerator, int denominator );
    void calculateGCD( Fraction& fraction );

private:
    void calculate( int numerator, int denominator );

}; // FractionWithGCD

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FractionWithGCD() - Default Constructor
// User needs to use either calculateGCD function they will both create member
// variable fraction and calculate the GCD of that fraction storing the values.
FractionWithGCD::FractionWithGCD() :
m_gcd( 0 ) {
} // FractionWithGCD

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FractionWithGCD() - Takes Two Integers - Will construct a fraction
// variable and calculate the GCD upon construction    
FractionWithGCD::FractionWithGCD( int numerator, int denominator ) :
m_gcd( 0 ) {
    calculate( numerator, denominator );
} // FractionWithGCD

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FractionWithGCD() - Takes a Fraction struct, saves it and calculates the GCD.
FractionWithGCD::FractionWithGCD( Fraction& fraction ) :
m_gcd( 0 ) {
    calculate( fraction.numerator, fraction.denominator );
} // FractionWithGCD

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculateGCD() - Calls private member calculate() - If this function is called
// again, the current fraction and GCD will be overwritten.
void FractionWithGCD::calculateGCD( int, numerator, int denominator ) {
    calculate( numerator, denominator );
} // calculateGCD

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculateGCD() - Calls private member calculate() - If this function is called
// again, the current fraction and GCD will be overwritten.
void FractionWithGCD::calculateGCD( Fraction& fraction ) {
    calculate( fraction.numerator, calculate.denominator );
 } // calculateGCD

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculate() - Private Method - Responsible For Checking If Fraction Is
// Valid That The Denominator Is Not 0, Saved The Fraction To Member Variable
// And Does All The Work To Calculate The GSD And Saves It Into Member Variable
void FractionWithGCD::calculate( int numerator, int denominator ) {
    // Check Denominator For 0 To Prevent Possible Division By 0
    if ( denominator == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Error: Division By 0." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    // Save Our Fraction
    m_fraction.numerator = numerator; 
    m_fraction.denominator = denominator;

    // Temp Stack Variables To Work With
    int remainder   = 0;

    do {
        remainder   = numerator % denominator;
        numerator   = denominator;
        denominator = remainder;
    } while ( denominator > 0 );

    m_gcd = numerator;

} // Calculate
```

Comment: If you need dynamic memory you can create an instance of this class and store it into a std::share_ptr or a std::unique_ptr pending on your needs. The only time I would use new or delete is, if the item is short lived and you know for a fact that you will be the only one to delete it. If you are not sure if another caller or user is going to delete it or not, it is safe to use shared if multiple objects need it or unique if it belongs solely to one object.